# ¿Cómo obtener la dirección IP del cliente cuando en el servidor existe un balanceador de carga en Java?

Tags: java, aplicación-web, jboss-eap

Yo deseo obtener la dirección IP de los usuarios cuando se conectan a mi aplicación Web Java que está en un servidor JBOSS 6.3.2, en cluster y con balanceador de carga.

He probado unas soluciones, pero siempre me devuelven una sola IP, supongo que es la del balanceador. Este es el código que he estado utilizando:

```
private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = {
    "X-Forwarded-For",
    "Proxy-Client-IP",
    "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_VIA",
    "REMOTE_ADDR"};

public static String getClientIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
        String ip = request.getHeader(header);
        if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            return ip;
        }
    }
    return request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```